# How can I recursively search a Tree that uses an observableArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, knockout.js

I have a sidebar index menu which is a complex nested tree. This is created with a TreeNode datastructure like so:

```
function TreeNode(data){
    var self = this;

    self.key = ko.observable(data.key);
    self.label = ko.observable(data.label);
    self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.documentPropertyClassId = ko.observable(data.document_property_class_id);

    // Recursively create new children
    $.each(data.children, function(index, child){
            self.children.push(new TreeNode(child));
    });
    self.isFilterable = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        // If a node has no children, then it's a filterable
        return !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.children).length;
    });
}
```

And this is created from an Ajax request:

```
var response = getData(label, id);

response.then(function(data){
    self.treeNode(new TreeNode(data, self));
});
```

This results in a list like so but not actually (I copied the link from elsewhere) http://jsbin.com/Awipoku/13/edit?html,css,js,output

What I'm struggling with is recursively searching the Tree for a node that contains a matching documentPropertyClassId.

This is what I found on the internet which I am trying to adapt to the Knockout Js realm:

```
function searchTree(element, matchingTitle){
    if(element.title == matchingTitle){
        return element;
    }else if (element.children != null){
        var i;
        var result = null;
        for(i=0; result == null && i < element.children.length; i++){
            result = searchTree(element.children[i], matchingTitle);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
function searchTree(node, matchingPropertyId){
    if(node.documentPropertyClassId() == matchingPropertyId) {
        console.log("found");
        return node;
    } else if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(node.children).length > 0) {
       var result = null;
       console.log("hello");
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(node.children(), function(child) {
           console.log(child.label());
           result = searchTree(child.children, matchingPropertyId);
       });
       return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: How far did you get? I can see you need to use `result = searchTree(child, matchingPropertyId);` instead of `child.children`

Comment: Is there any difference between observable and simple tree?

Comment: Could you create a [mcve]? It's kinda tough to fill in the blanks without access to your actual context/code.